# How to load specific workbook from excel sheet using python Pandas based on current date

Tags: python, excel, pandas, numpy

I have a excel sheet which contains no. of workbook tab named as 1st,2nd,3rd,4th and so on. I want to open the workbook based on current date. For example: if today is 20th Aug, then i want to only open 20th Aug workbook and do my further action. Currently I am using pandas and  able to open workbook by providing sheet name but i want to open by comparing current date condition to open the workbook.

Can anyone suggest or help ?

Comment: `pd.Timestamp.now().strftime("YOUR_FORMAT")` is all your need.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Henry. How this will help me to read particular workbook. ?

Comment: `pd.Timestamp.now()` gives you a `Timestamp` with current date. Use `strftime` to get your desired format ([read this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) if you are unfamiliar with formatting) then pass the string to your `pd.read_excel`.

Comment: Thanks Henry , I tried to do this but now format is an issue to me. My workbook tab name is like 1st,2nd,3rd and so on. I am able to read only if workbook name is like number 1,2,3 ,etc. Any suggests how to read sheet name like 20th

data=pd.Timestamp.now().strftime('%d')
df1=pd.read_excel("aug.xlsx",sheet_name=data,skiprows=3)

above code will open the workbook with dates as 1,2,3,4,5 but tab name i have is 1st,2nd,3rd.

Any suggestion how to read this

Answer (score 0):

As a suggestion, you could define a `tuple` with all the expected names and *then* access it with the index given as a result of `pd.Timestamp.now().strftime` command (as suggested in the comments). In addition to use the `day` to access the `sheet` with the expected name, you can extend the behavior and also get the `month` from `strftime` for opening the `xlsx` file.

Input **sep.xlsx**
[image: excel-sheets]

```
import pandas as pd

order = ('1st', '2nd', '3rd', '4th', '5th', '6th', '7th', '8th', '9th', '10th',
         '11th', '12th', '13th', '14th', '15th', '16th', '17th', '18th', '19th',
         '20th', '21st', '22nd', '23rd', '24th', '25th', '26th', '27th', '28th',
         '29th', '30th', '31st'
        )

day, month = pd.Timestamp.now().strftime("%d %b").split()
day = order[int(day)-1]
month = month.lower()

df1 = pd.read_excel(f"{month}.xlsx", sheet_name=day, skiprows=3)
```